# My form parameters are not saving/inserting to my database, even though the form is submitting the paramters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

Here is my form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <%= simple_form_for SkyscraperApplications.create, :url=>"/about/skyscraper/submit", :method=>"post" do |f| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name"><%=t ".company_name"%></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div><%= f.input :name,  :label=>false %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="employees"><%=t ".no_of_employees"%></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div><%= f.input :employee_count, :label=>false %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="employees"><%=t ".usecase"%></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.select :usecase, options_for_select([["Select One", ""], "CAD/Render", "Video Production/Editing", "Music Production", "Game Design", "Email/Web", "Other"])%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Administrator"><%=t ".admin_email"%></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div><%= f.input :email_admin, :label=>false %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Administrator"><%=t ".what_you_do"%></label>
        <div class="controls">
        <div><%= f.input :what_you_do, :label=>false, :as => :text, :input_html => { :rows => 4 }%></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="test-drive-submit"><%= f.button :submit, t(".submit")%></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

here is my controller method:

```
def create
if @skyscraper=SkyscraperApplications.new(:email_admin => params[:skyscraper_applications][:email_admin],:employee_count=>params[:skyscraper_applications][:employee_count],:name=>params[:skyscraper_applications][:name],:usecase=>params[:skyscraper_applications][:usecase],:what_you_do=>params[:skyscraper_applications][:what_you_do])
 @skyscraper.save
    redirect_to "/about/skyscraper", :notice => t("skyscraper_saved")

else
 redirect_to "/about/skyscraper", :notice => t("skyscraper_failed")

end
```

And here is my console:

```
Processing by AboutController#skyscraper as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"fpIBeQKOqnP1As118fWwG5/LXdyT3QL5dLBYRDgkGNq8PfwldrvC9QrsZnJ+pX9+mvhCN3N9yW9p2q7fdhDdhg==", "skyscraper_applications"=>{"name"=>"example", "employee_count"=>"5", "usecase"=>"CAD/Render", "email_admin"=>"email@email.com", "what_you_do"=>"example"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

  SkyRoutine Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sky_routines".* FROM "sky_routines"  ORDER BY "sky_routines"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "skyscraper_applications" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-04-16 19:29:16.070954"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-16 19:29:16.070954"]]
   (2.1ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered about/skyscraper.html.erb within layouts/application (23.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 82.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

So as you can see I submit my form, it picks up the params but doesn't insert into my database and save like I want it to. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: It could be something in the model.  Can you please post the code for the `SkyscraperApplications` model?

Comment: `class SkyscraperApplications < ActiveRecord::Base    
 attr_accessor :email_admin, :employee_count, :name, :usecase, :what_you_do



end`
Thank you!!

Comment: The problem is that attr_accessor line. I just posted an answer...

Comment: whats the point of SkyscraperApplications.create in your form object? Why not follow rails crud conventions? Manual complication of things just does it worse for you

Comment: Is it not calling my controller method? What change do you suggest I make there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have defined `attr_accessor`s for the attributes that you are trying to save.  `attr_accessor` defines setter and getter methods, which override any attributes of the same name. Once you remove the attr_accessors Rails should save the values to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the attr_accessors but it is still doing the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Rails 4.0.0 or higher, you need to use strong parameters when doing mass assignment. You also need to fix your logic in the controller. It should look like this:

```
def create
  @skyscraper = SkyscraperApplications.new(sky_scraper_params)
  if @skyscraper.save
    redirect_to "/about/skyscraper", :notice => t("skyscraper_saved")
  else
    redirect_to "/about/skyscraper", :notice => t("skyscraper_failed")
end

private

def  sky_scraper_params
  params.require(:skyscraper_applications).permit(:name, :employee_count, :usecase, :email_admin, :what_you_do
end
```

Comment: thanks for that,  i added in strong params and adjusted by method, but i am still getting the same thing in my console. Could it be something with my form? this has me so stumped.

Comment: which notice are you getting, saved or failed?

Comment: seems like you don't have the attributes in the db or something, post the schema.

Comment: im not getting a notice. here is my schema:                                                         `create_table "skyscraper_applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",           limit: 255
    t.integer  "employee_count"
    t.string   "usecase",        limit: 255
    t.string   "email_admin",    limit: 255
    t.string   "what_you_do",    limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end`

Comment: you're submitting to the wrong action, post your route

Comment: `post "about/skyscraper/submit" => "skyscraper_applications#create"`

Comment: try using new instead of create `simple_form_for SkyscraperApplications.new`